# Re-render pagination after change limit per page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a datatable :

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('#table_list').DataTable ({
        "bJqueryUI": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "./action/list_json.php",
        "iDisplayLength": 50, // default nb to display 
        "aaSorting": [],
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": 'Show <select id="list"><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select> lines'
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "bVisible":false }, { "bSortable":false }, { "bSortable":false }, { "bSortable":false }, { "bSortable":false }
        ]
    });
}) ;
```

After changing the number of lines to display per page my back return good information :

```
....
"iTotalRecords" => "28"
"iTotalDisplayRecords" => 25
```

But in view I have a pagination with page 1 activated, normally I should have a pagination with 2 pages : 25 items on first page and 3 items on the second;

But I have something like:

[image]

The problem is that rendering of pagination is not done. What can I try next?

Comment: what version of datatable are you using? can you create working code snippet to recreate the problem?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you have 25 displayable records (out of a total of 28), and if you show 25 records per page, then that equals 1 page of data. Those extra 3 records are (or should have been) filtered out by your server-side code - that is what [`iTotalDisplayRecords`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) means. That is telling DataTables that there are only 25 records, _after filtering_.

Comment: Another unrelated point: You should consider updating all your options and parameters to use the modern DataTables names - as listed [here](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert). Also, the server-side value for `iTotalDisplayRecords` is now `recordsFiltered` (see [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)).

Answer (score 0):

you need to add below two attributes in datatable configuration

```
"bPaginate":true,
"sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
```

your code should look like

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('#table_list').DataTable ({
        "bJqueryUI": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "./action/list_json.php",
        "bPaginate":true,
        "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 50, // default nb to display 
        "aaSorting": [],
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": 'Show <select id="list"><option value="25">25</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select> lines'
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "bVisible":false }, { "bSortable":false }, { "bSortable":false }, { "bSortable":false }, { "bSortable":false }
        ]
    });
}) ;
```

NOTE: use `"pagingType": "full_numbers"` if `"sPaginationType":"full_numbers"` does not work. It depends on your datatable plugin version

Comment: is not working, I have the same issue :(

Comment: Version of datatable is : 1.10.18

Comment: if I remove from my query : `limit ".$_REQUEST['iDisplayStart']. ",".$_REQUEST['iDisplayLength']` is working fine the pagination @Bhushan Kawadkar

Comment: ok, may be these attributes are not required at all. did that solved your purpose?